# symfony2 class validator for sluggable entiy

Tags: class, symfony, constraints

I have a class constraint for an entity with the field slug. I want to do some checks of the slug in a custom class contraint, but in the constraint the value of `getSlug()` is empty.

```
// my custom class validator
public function isValid( $page, Constraint $constraint ) {
    $slug = $page->getSlug();
```

=> `$slug` is empty.

Here is my Entity

```
class page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Page();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm( new PageType(), $entity );
    $form->bindRequest( $request );
```

The custom class validator is called in `$form->bindRequest( $request )`. I think, slug is not set, because doctrine will set it at the pre persist event. But this event is called later at `$em->persist( $entity )`.

Is there a way to get to the slug of the page in my class constraint?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

Like you said, the slug is generated on `prePersist` event.

Are you sure you have to validate slug? If it's the case, remove `@Gedmo\Slug` annotation and create it by yourself... But I'm not sure it's a really good idea.

Comment: Maybe I do not need a validator for the slug. What I need is a unique combination of user_slug/page_slug as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968300/unique-slugs-with-multi-entities-in-symfony2